# Register multiple implementations for a single Open Generic with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I'm using the Simple Injector as my IoC container. I have developed a number of (excuse me probably using the wrong term) *partially closed* implementations, for a single generic interface.

I would like to be in a position to request the generic interface, and based on the types supplied, have Simple Injector return the correct class implementation. (I can understand this may be a no-no as implementations could overlap if done wrong etc. but I'd still like to know if it can be done.)

Based on the code snippets below, how can I configure Simple Injector to return me an instance of `ITrim<Ford, Green>`?

Common base class layer:

```
public interface IColour { }
public interface IVehicle { }
public interface ITrim<TVehicle, TColour>
    where TVehicle : IVehicle
    where TColour : IColour
{
    void Trim(TVehicle vehicle, TColour colour);
}

public abstract class TrimVehicle<TVehicle, TColour> : ITrim<TVehicle, TColour>
    where TVehicle : IVehicle
    where TColour : IColour
{
    public virtual void Trim(TVehicle vehicle, TColour colour) { }
}
```

Middle layer, providing common code for a type of vehicle:

```
public abstract class Green : IColour { }
public abstract class Blue : IColour { }
public abstract class Car : IVehicle { }
public abstract class Bike : IVehicle { }

public abstract class TrimCar<TCar, TColour> : TrimVehicle<TCar, TColour>
    where TCar : Car
    where TColour : IColour
{
    public override void Trim(TVehicle vehicle, TColour colour)
    {
        base.Trim(vehicle, colour);
    }
}

public abstract class TrimBike<TBike, TColour> : TrimVehicle<TBike, TColour>
    where TBike : Bike
    where TColour : IColour
{
    public override void Trim(TVehicle vehicle, TColour colour)
    {
        base.Trim(vehicle, colour);
    }
}
```

Final layer, providing more specific implementations:

```
public class Ford : Car { }
public class TrimFord<TFord, TColour> : TrimCar<TFord, TColour>
    where TFord : Ford
    where TColour : IColour
{
    public override void Trim(TVehicle vehicle, TColour colour)
    {
        base.Trim(vehicle, colour);
    }
}

public class Yamaha : Bike { }
public class TrimYamaha<TYamaha, TColour> : TrimBike<TYamaha, TColour>
    where TYamaha : Yamaha
    where TColour : IColour
{
    public override void Trim(TVehicle vehicle, TColour colour)
    {
        base.Trim(vehicle, colour);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TLDR;**

```cs
container.Register(typeof(ITrim<,>), typeof(ITrim<,>).Assembly);
```

Long, but outdated answer:

A very complicated question, with a very simple answer:

```cs
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(ITrim<,>), typeof(TrimCar<,>));
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(ITrim<,>), typeof(TrimFord<,>));
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(ITrim<,>), typeof(TrimYamaha<,>));
```

This works, because Simple Injector respects any generic type constraint of a given type (or at least, any it handles any nasty bizarre type constraint that I could think of). So as long as you make sure the registered open generic types (`TrimCar`, `TrimFord`, and `TrimYamaha`) do not overlap, it will work as expected.

If they do overlap, the container will throw an exception telling you that multiple observers of the `ResolveUnregisteredType` event tried to register {some type}.

Although you should be careful that the use of these overlapping types does not complicate your application, in general I find the use of generic type constraints very convenient and I use it all the time (especially when registering decorators).

**UPDATE**

If you have a set of non-generic decorators, the current implementation of `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` can not distinguish them from 'normal' types, and it tries to register them. If you don't want that, you can register your types as follows:

```cs
var types = OpenGenericBatchRegistrationExtensions.GetTypesToRegister(
   typeof(ITrim<,>), typeof(ITrim<,>).Assembly)
   .Where(type => !type.Name.EndsWith("Decorator");

container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(ITrim<,>), types);
```

The `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` extension methods use the `GetTypesToRegister` internally as well.

**UPDATE 2**

The `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` method of Simple Injector 2 now recognizes non-generic decorators, so with v2 you are able to simply do this:

```cs
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
    typeof(ITrim<,>), 
    typeof(ITrim<,>).Assembly);
```

Much easier, don't you think?

**UPDATE 3**

Simple Injector v3 obsoleted `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` and removed them completely from v4. For v3 and up, `Register` can be used instead:

```cs
container.Register(typeof(ITrim<,>), typeof(ITrim<,>).Assembly);
```

Comment: thanks, even simpler than I'd hoped! Is it possible for me to register them all in one call?

Comment: @qujck: There is no support for doing them all in one call. You could write an extension method yourself quite easily though.

Comment: Turns out that the difficulty of a standard extension method is having a standard construct to ignore decorators

Comment: @qujck: do you mean the `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric`?

Comment: I was creating an extension method to find and register each non abstract instance of ITrim, but I also have decoraters for ITrim that, therefore, also implement ITrim but need to be ignored as they will be registered using RegisterDecorator elsewhere. It makes the Linq query a bit longer and made me realise I can't have one RegisterManyOpenGenericForOpenGenericIgnoringDecorators extension method.

Comment: So your decorators are not generic types? `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` automatically skips generic types. If those decorators are not generic, you can use the `OpenGenericBatchRegistrationExtensions.GetTypesToRegister` method to find the types. See my update.